# UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void mono.android.text.TextWatcherImplementor

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, release

I'm working on **Xamarin.Android** project and after having updated all libraries to the newest and on Release version I have such an exception:

```
07-26 09:17:08.681 9603-9603/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: xx.xx.xx, PID: xxxx
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void mono.android.text.TextWatcherImplementor.n_beforeTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, int) (tried Java_mono_android_text_TextWatcherImplementor_n_1beforeTextChanged and Java_mono_android_text_TextWatcherImplementor_n_1beforeTextChanged__Ljava_lang_CharSequence_2III)
    at mono.android.text.TextWatcherImplementor.n_beforeTextChanged(Native Method)
    at mono.android.text.TextWatcherImplementor.beforeTextChanged(TextWatcherImplementor.java:41)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:10892)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6220)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6170)
    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:146)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6127)
    at android.widget.TextView.setTransformationMethod(TextView.java:2755)
    at md5964384997be3f2086f58afbb264e9147.LoginView.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at md5964384997be3f2086f58afbb264e9147.LoginView.onCreate(LoginView.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

I've added such methods

```
public void Include(TextView text)
    {
        text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.TextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.BeforeTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.Hint = $"{text.Hint}";
    }

    public void Include(EditText text)
    {
        text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.TextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.BeforeTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.Hint = $"{text.Hint}";
    }

    public void Include(Android.Support.Design.Widget.TextInputEditText text)
    {
        text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.TextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.BeforeTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
        text.Hint = $"{text.Hint}";
    }
```

to the `LinkerPleaseInclude` but it still does not help. Any idea?

I tried to clear everything (bin, obj, app, visualstudio etc.)

Comment: Delete the folder bin and obj in your Forms and Android Project. Then clean and rebuild it.

Comment: I tried already, it did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue. See the following issue for more details:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3263#issuecomment-514046705

1. Create a [custom linker configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker)
2. Add the following to it

```
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="Mono.Android">
    <type fullname="Android.Text.ITextWatcherInvoker" preserve="all" />
  </assembly>
</linker>
```

Although this is a temporary fix, we are working on resolving it in a future release.

Comment: Please also comment or add a reaction on the issue so we can actively know how many people are running into it!

Comment: I just checked this solution, and it looks like it works.

Comment: Btw, there's a lot of missing information in the documentation, where to add the file (Shared project or native?), if it has naming requirements etc. Also, how is it different than the skip linking option? I am talking about the custom linker configuration file. I have a different issue, not the TextWatcher related one.

Comment: @iBobb Open up an issue on the documentation! They should all be in the context of the Android project.

Comment: @Jon Douglas there already is one if you go to the custom linker configuration link above, I just added a comment on it.